# How to change the IP in tor whonix gateway, not tor browser?

Tags: tor

I want to change the IP of the exit node in a tor whonix gateway. Is there a file with which I can achieve the same? Or any idea on how to do it? I am trying to change the IP of the tor in a browser, but don't know how the IP of the exit node is created. Who creates the IP for the exit node? Is it a proxy server?

Answer (score 1):

See the Whonix article on [Controlling and Monitoring Tor](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Tor_Controller).

SSH in to your Whonix gateway, run the `arm` command and type `n` to get a new circuit.  By building a new circuit, you should effectively get a new IP since the Exit relay will change with the new circuit.

If that doesn't give you a new IP, from within `arm`, you can try a couple more things:

- Press `m` to open the menu
- Scroll down to `New Identity` and press Enter.

Or

- Press the right arrow key until you get the `Control Interpretor` window
- Press `Enter` to use the panel
- Type `signal newnym` and press `Enter` to send a signal to Tor to get a new circuit with a different exit node